# Will a US tablet imported into the UK get OTA updates?

Tags: ota-update

I would very much like a Samsung PM-580 (Tab A 10.1, with S Pen) but Samsung are either being slow to release it in the UK, or potentially might not at all.  Via Amazon.com I can import one to the UK at what I consider to be a reasonable price, and I can see no technological problems with using it here.

However this tablet is getting an OTA update to Nougat very soon (if not already), and obviously I'd want this for mine.  So:

> Will a US-serial number tablet still get its OTA updates in the UK?

It would seem odd to me for the answer to be "no", since this would involve Samsung insisting that you connected to a network in a particular location before giving you the OTA update.  But it would be reassuring to know for definite before investing my cash, and perhaps others have had similar experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you bought it in the US it will get otas.